# How to add a value to a field in the same model when the model is saved - django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a django model that looks like this...

```
class Account(models.Model):
  account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  deposited_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  opening_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  current_balance = models.CharField(max_length=9)
```

Inside my `admin.py` file, I have the `current_balance` field set to readonly. I would like the current balance to be the sum of `deposited_amount` and `opening_balance` hence I have implemented a signal to try and handle that...

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Account, dispatch_uid="update_current_balance")
def update_current_balance(sender, **kwargs):
  created = kwargs['created']
  instance = kwargs['instance']
    if created:
      instance.current_balance = F('deposited_amount') + F('opening_balance')
```

Creating new accounts works fine but the current_balance doesn't get updated. What am I missing here?

Also, I'm thinking that in the event that either the deposited amount or opening_balance is updated, I will need the current balance updated too so should I maybe remove the `if created` check, or do I create another signal?

Comment: Because you're doing it in post_save, so the change is not itself saved; you should probably do it in pre_save. But really, think carefully about whether you actually need to save this value at all. Calculating the sum of two fields is trivial to do on the fly when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call `instance.save` in your signal to update your instance. following code can solve your issue

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Account, dispatch_uid="update_current_balance")
def update_current_balance(sender, **kwargs):
  created = kwargs['created']
  instance = kwargs['instance']
    if created:
      instance.current_balance = F('deposited_amount') + F('opening_balance')
      instance.save()
    elif 'deposited_amount' in  kwargs['updated_fields']:
      # do your work and don't forget to call .save()
```

Or you need to do this in `pre_save` signal.

## Update For TransactionLog

We are going to have three account. `User` will keep information about owner of Account, `UserAccount` will keep information about how much money user currently have. `TransactionLog` will keep all transaction in our system. So that

1. This can work as our `Truth Table`. If an user clam that I should have much money in my account that is not currently showing. We can give him a statement.
2. We can separate responsibity. Every model should serve single responsibity.

#### Possible Models

At first we should have `UserModel`. This can be `Default Django  User Mode` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) Or we can extend `AbstractBaseUser` model [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)


class TransactionLog(models.Model):
    CREDIT = 'CREDIT'
    DEBIT = 'DEBIT'
    OPENING_ACCOUNT = 'OPENING_ACCOUNT'
    DEPOSITE_INTO_ACCOUNT = 'DEPOSITE_INTO_ACCOUNT'
    WITHDRAW_FROM_ACCOUNT = 'WITHDRAW_FROM_ACCOUNT'
    UNKNOWN = 'UNKNOWN'
    TRANSACTION_TYPES = (
        (CREDIT, 'credit'),
        (DEBIT, 'debit'),
    )
    REASON_TYPES = ((OPENING_ACCOUNT, 'OPENING_ACCOUNT'), (DEPOSITE_INTO_ACCOUNT,
                                                     'deposite_into_account'),
                    (WITHDRAW_FROM_ACCOUNT, 'withDRAW_FROM_ACCOUNT'), (UNKNOWN, 'unknown'))

    type = models.CharField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPES, max_length=6)
    reason = models.CharField(
        choices=REASON_TYPES, max_length=255, default=UNKNOWN)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now for every entry in `TransactionLog` in our system, we will tigger a signal. Based on `reason` and `type` we will update our `Account`. I must mention `opening account` and `deposite first amount` should be different. There must have different entry in `TransactionLog` table. `TransactionLog` is our `Truth Log Table`. This should log every single `transaction`.

And our signal will be like

```
from .models import Account, TransactionLog

@receiver(post_save, sender=TransactionLog, dispatch_uid="transaction log entry")
def update_user_account(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.reason == TransactionLog.OPENING_ACCOUNT:  
        Account.objects.create(user=instance.user_id, balance=instance.amount) 
    else:
        user_account = Account.objects.get(user=instance.user_id)
        if instance.type == TransactionLog.CREDIT:
            user_account.balance = F('balance') + instance.amount
        else: # For Debit 
            user_account.balance = F('balance') - instance.amount

        user_account.save()
```

One important thing i want to add. As this is transaction related insert in our models, Both entry in `TransactionLog` and `Account` should have `transaction_automic` chain. Even we can do this in our Model Settings [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#atomic-requests) So that all our views/HTTP_REQUEST_API should have that.

Hope this will help.

Comment: That worked. The current_balance is now successfully being added. However, when I update `deposited_amount` for example, nothing happens. Could you help me with the second part of the signal i.e what if the object is not being created but updated? How do I also update the current_balance?

Comment: can you please tell me one thing, whenever you changed `deposited_amount` is that always need to add your `current_balance`. Say your `current_balance` is 30K and your first time `opening_balance` was 10K and `deposited_balance` was 20K. And then you change your `deposited_balance` to 30K. what does it actually means. Is new 30K being created your account or `current_deposited_balance` - `previous_deposited_balance` ( 30K - 20K = 10K ) is credited to your account ?

Comment: If the `current_balance` was 30k i.e an `opening_balance` of 10K and an initial `deposited_balance` of 20K and we changed the `deposited_balance` to 30K, the `current_balance` should reflect the difference between the old and the new. The 10K difference would be added to the `current_balance`. Same thing would happen if changes were made to the `opening_balance`.

Comment: Or we could just recompute the current balance using the new `deposited_amount` and `opening_balance`.

Comment: @NelsonKing if thats the case then you can just do that with same code. just check `deposited_balance` is in updated_fields or not. But i think instead of doing this from `Account` , I think you should maintain e `TransactionLog` table as `truth_table` and keep updating user account from that. If you want i can write an explanation about it.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187963/discussion-between-shakil-and-nelson-king).